# \tilde in parenthesis

Tags: math-mode, tilde

How could this command be done? I mean a `\tilde`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\sptilde` from `amsxtra`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra}

\begin{document}

$\tilde{f}+\tilde{g}=(f+g)^{\sptilde}=0$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, define a suitable command:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ptilde}{\tilde{\mspace{6mu}}}

\begin{document}

$\tilde{f}+\tilde{g}=(f+g)\ptilde=0$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean `\sim`?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$(f+g)^\sim$
\end{document}
```